# jquery click function not working for dynamically added fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dynamically append some html code (contains input type checkbox) using jquery.
the data showing perfectly with class and ids
but when i tried to access those input tags (input type checkbox) by using jquery it is not happening.
Why?
and is there any solution?

My Html

```
<div id="divData"></div>
```

My Scripts

```
<script>
    function RollBackVehicles() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Controller")',
            async: false,
            data: { ID: 1235 },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (d) {
                var c = "";
                for (var b = 0; b < d.length; b++) {
                    c += "<p> <input type='checkbox'class='clscheck' id='" + d[b].Id + "'/> <span>" + d[b].Value + "</span>"
                }
                $("#divdata").html(c);
            }
        });
    }
    $(".clscheck").change(function () {
        alert("Changed");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Setting his up in https://jsfiddle.net/ will help you get a solution faster.

Comment: No.Am not getting any errors in console

Comment: Even just typing your question title into Google _verbatim_ would have lead you to results already. Please make an actual effort before asking here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this for on any new element added to dom , because you are adding dynamic elements to DOM

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
    var data="<p> <input type='checkbox'class='clscheck' id='checkData'/> <span>Test</span>";
    $("#divdata").html(data);
 });
   
   $("#divdata").on("change", ".clscheck", function(){
         alert("Changed");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divdata"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('change','.clscheck', function () {
        alert("change");
     });
 });
```

Comment: Ummm... document has a change event now?

Comment: no your checkbox has try with and let me know is it working ?

Comment: Yes ,,,,Its working

Answer (score 0):

Since you you element is dynamically added you need to use reference of static element. Your code might look like.

```
$("#divData").on('click', '.clscheck',function () {
    alert("Changed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use pure javascript event handler binding, as for any Dom object added dynamically after the document is loaded.

notation example:

```
object.addEventListener("change", myScript);
```